# sleep function in c crazy bug in linux

Tags: c, linux

i have this simple code"
printinterval in int

```
sleep(printinterval/3);
displayPrint();  //// just some printing func
sleep(printinterval/3);
displayPrint(); 
sleep(printinterval-2*(int)(printinterval/3));
displayPrint();
```

the problem is that it doest not do the delay the right way,
jumps over 1 sleep

but

```
sleep(printinterval/3);
printf("\n");
displayPrint();  //// just some printing func
printf("\n");    
sleep(printinterval/3);
printf("\n");    
displayPrint();
printf("\n"); 
sleep(printinterval-2*(int)(printinterval/3));
printf("\n");
displayPrint();
```

works like a charm

any ideas?
thx :)

EDITED:
thx for the help
found this way to fix it

```
fflush(stdout); // Will now print everything in the stdout buffer
```

and again, thx

Comment: How is `printInterval` defined and what is its value ?

Comment: The `printf("\n")` calls are flushing the output.  In the example where you're not using them the output is probably getting buffered and you don't see some of the `displayPrint()` output until long after.

Comment: This: `sleep(printinterval-2*(int)(printinterval));` doesn't make any sense, that looks like it would produce a negative delay for any positive value of `printinterval`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The stream is buffered, and flushed when a `\n` is encountered.

See:[Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)